# Get CLIPS/Jess output in string variable

Tags: java, clips, jess

i have integrated jess with java in netbeans. I want to access output in a string variable.

when I (run) the .clp file and give it an input, it shows me output, but I want to get this output in string variable. How can I do this?? please help. this is my .clp file code.

```
(deftemplate problem
(multislot name)
(slot symptom))

(deffacts probelms
(probelm (name (create$ "Air filter"  "fuel injector problem" "fuel pressure regualtor")) 
    (symptom Black-Smoke))
    )

(defrule reading-input
=>
(printout t "Enter the symptom your car Shows: " )
(assert (var (read))))

(defrule checking-input
(var ?symptom)
(probelm  (symptom ?symptom1)(name $?name1))
(test (eq ?symptom ?symptom1)) 
 =>
(printout t "Problems can be " $?name1 crlf))
```

code to run this in java

```
 public static string path="C:\Users\Taimoor Mirza\Documents\car.CLP";  
  Rete r=new Rete();
   r.batch(path);
   r.reset();
   r.run();
```

this run good and when I enter Black-Smoke , this gives me possible symptoms on running exe.
I want to get these Symptoms in a string. how can I get this result in String???

Comment: It depends how you run the CLP from your Java application. One possibility is to use a StringBuilder object in the CLP file to accumulate the output.

Comment: I have updated my question. please help. I am waiting for ur reply.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a Writer and tell Jess to use it:

```
Writer writer = new StringWriter();
rete.addOutputRouter( "t", writer );
// run Jess writing to router "t"
System.out.println( writer.toString() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the section about I/O Routers in the manual, here: http://www.jessrules.com/jess/docs/71/library.html#routers . Use a `java.io.StringWriter` as an output router, and then retrieve the text from the `StringWriter`.

Comment: Sir, I have updated my question, please help me. I am waiting for ur answer.